# Parts of mesh Rendering White

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

This is my first blender project. I am creating an ad for a phone. Everything looks OK in object view but when rendering in cycles there are white patches where it should be black. I thought the subdivided was causing it but  I removed the subdivide and I am having the same issue still. Here is a screenshot and the blender file. If anyone could help that would be great.

[image: Screenshot of Issue]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a white phone that is not visible in viewport but active for render.
[image: outliner]

Comment: Thanks that worked. Was so much simpler than I thought!

Comment: You can use layers in 2.79 and collections in 2.8 to control what is visible/renderable